# How can I determine if I've set up my phone improperly or if someone is just sending me messages for someone else?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

Hi Iv been having a problem with my iphone 4s. i have recieved 2 messages from my ex partners phone it did not come up as an imessage only a normal message. He did not send the messages we believe somehow either the number has been cloned or somehow this person has got hold of his apple id and managing to send a message which appears to come from my ex partner. would be much appreciated if someone can help me with this problem. Also my partner has been in touch with his network and changed his number. after that i recieved a 2nd message coming from his old contact which is by the sounds of it still linked to his apple id

Apologies for confusion I just would like to know how a message can sent from someone who I know but that person has not actually sent it. The messages came through on the thread messages that my ex partner has previously sent but not as an iMessage it's causing great confusion how it has been done.

Basically, I don't get how things work so I can know if it's something I can change or if it's just the sender messing up. How can I verify my device is receiving only my messages?

Comment: Hmm, looks like you forgot the important part: what is your question here?

Comment: iMessages come in as blue. They are routed through Apple's servers. Messages that are green are sent using the old SMS protocol and have nothing to do with iPhones or iMessage or one's Apple ID. You can't "clone" an Apple ID. You can't even deactivate an Apple ID in fact. I suggest you book an appointment with an Apple Genius and show them the problem. They'll be more than happy to help solve it and explain what went on. They'll also have an easier time than us on the Internet.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. To avoid getting answers that don't really solve your problem, the question will be closed FOR NOW until it can be improved. Please edit your question to make it clearer so we can reopen it. Read [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more ideas to improve the question. Confusing questions are closed so they don't attract a scattering of answers before they're in a form that is likely to get a clear answer; your question can be reopened at any time if you or someone on your behalf suitably amends it.

Comment: After a couple of friendly edits, I've reopened this, but it still needs substantial improvement and might need to be closed if more details can't be added on what Kayleigh has done to try to troubleshoot this. I can't see anything but guesses being provided based on the lack of specific data or access to the actual device to test assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I would sign out of iMessage on the device and ensure the carrier is only sending messages to that phone number.

Once you've ruled out SMS to the old and new number being delivered, you can re-enable iMessage and test Apple's delivery to that phone.

It's almost certainly a problem with the sender's address book having wrong numbers, but removing and then adding iMessage should clear any mistaken routing if that was the cause.